# Is mongoDB perfectly compatible with windows server 64bit 2012 r2?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to check if MongoDB 3.0 is perfectly compatible with Win Server 64 bit 2012 R2? Do we need to install the hotfix for Win 2012 as well like we do in win 2008 r2?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows hotfix that you are referring to only applies to Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008r2. See: ["33" DOS error code when memory memory-mapped files are cleaned by using the FlushViewOfFile() function in Windows 7 or in Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2731284).

As noted in the guide to [install MongoDB on Windows](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/), you only need to install the hotfix if you are running affected versions of Windows.

This hotfix is not available for older versions of Windows (2008 or Vista) and is not required for newer versions of Windows (i.e. Server 2012).

Comment: If your going to answer a non-programming question on a programming site will you at least cast your vote for migration.